# Remove Special Characters and also exclude a word

Tags: c#, regex

We need to run a app that will process more than 1000000 urls. I can not replace the special characters of the segments in a separately way because will be a slow process. That why I need to process all the url in one call.

I need to remove the special characters in a url (in the segments of the url), the problem is this segments are names and can contains /.

When I build the url will concatenate the segments with {-} and the later replace with /.

```
var newUrl = RemoveSpecialCharacters(url).Replace("{-}","/")
```

This is my Regex

```
(?:(?<!")\{\-\}(?!"))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]
```

This part gets the special characters [^0-9a-zA-Z\s] but I can not make the expression ignore {-}

This the an example of url that I am using with the Regex

{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman-area{-}Lake Ha/vasu City{-}North Pointe-by-Read Homes{-}hola{*e}s!fsd3$^gdfg%
Code:

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("(?:(?<!")\{0\}(?!"))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return r.Replace(input, " ");
}
```

And the result have to be:

{-}Lake Havasu City{-}Kingman area{-}Lake Ha vasu City{-}North Pointe by Read Homes{-}hola e s fsd3 gdfg

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be using the alternation operator in context, placing what you want to exclude on the left-hand side using a capturing group to backreference the group inside of the replacement call and place what you want to replace on the right-hand side of the alternation.

```
String s = "hola !@ew#$%^&er3523wrerffser*()12345678{}#0#word{0}";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\{0})|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "hola ewer3523wrerffser123456780word{0}"
```

Comment: Well where does the `{0}` 0 come from?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex: `(?:(?<!")\{0\}(?!"))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]`
You allow 0-9, and you ignore 0? Why so confused?
New regex: `(?:(?<!")\(?!"))|[^1-9a-zA-Z\s]`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to replace all the special chars other than `{0}` with an empty string. Then you could try the below regex.

```
replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(\{0})|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]", "$1");
```

This would capture the `{0}` part as very first and then it matches all the other characters according to this `[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]` pattern, ie, any character but not of alphanumeric or spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lT3mL1/1)